# Split output from portable laptop charger

Tags: power-supply

I'm looking for a safe way to power two devices from my portable power source which only has one output. The power source is an [Intocircuit® Power Castle 26000 mAh External Battery](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Intocircuit-26000mAh-External-Notebooks-Lightning/dp/B00AV4M1LQ). Which can output 12 V, 16 V or 19 V.

And I want to power a Raspberry Pi 2 - which takes 5 V DC (maximum).

And this LCD, which needs 6.5 V if I am reading [the data sheet](http://www.beyondinfinite.com/lcd/Library/Samsung/LTM190E4-L02.pdf) correctly,

> Power Supply Voltage, VDD, Vss-0.5 6.5 V (1)

I figured it would be best to ask the experts rather than fry my electronics.

Comment: According to your link, the external battery can supply BOTH 5V and 12V/16V/19V simutaneously. But if you're going to use the higher-voltage output (higher power available?), you'll need a separate DC-DC converter to produce the 5V for your two devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a UBEC which will switch any voltage in the range 5.5V-26V to 5V (up to 4 amps).

E.g. UBEC for radio control plane (this is an example, not an endorsement).

Power the UBEC from your external battery (it doesn't matter which voltage you choose) and power the Pi/LCD screen from the UBEC's 5V output.

The end with the three pin socket is the UBEC output. Typically positive will be red and ground black. There is a third wire which may be ignored. It is used for a servo control signal which will not be needed for your usage.

Alternatively look for DC-DC buck converters. They are not quite so convenient as they need calibrating to output 5V.

Another possibility is a car cigar lighter type adapter. They will only take 12V as an input but may be more readily available dpending on where you live.

Answer quoted from here:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/36627/34975

Comment: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/5431/87077

Answer (score 1):

The voltages given for the LCD are the absolute maximums. Table 3.1 gives the typical supply voltage, 5V. Both devices can be powered from the same 3-5A switching regulator module.